# Parse JSON without top-level label in android

Tags: android, json, parsing

```
@Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create an array
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
            jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                    .getJSONfromURL("http://demo.cogzideltemplates.com/client/sedio/feed/home_feed?user_id=5&start=1");
            try {
                // Locate the array name in JSON
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("worldpopulation");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Retrive JSON Objects
                    map.put("rank", jsonobject.getString("rank"));
                    map.put("country", jsonobject.getString("country"));
                    map.put("population", jsonobject.getString("population"));
                    map.put("flag", jsonobject.getString("flag"));
                    // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                    arraylist.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

---

here is my code but this dosenot work for me because my 
json has no top level element how can i run it

give me some example

Comment: You just get it as a JsonArray

Answer (score 0):

It's something like that :

```
    String s ="[{    \"text\": \"Pain Intensity\",     \"question_number\": 1,     \"id\": 1}, {    \"text\": \"Personal Care (washing, dressing, etc.)\",     \"question_number\": 2,     \"id\": 2}, {    \"text\": \"Lifting\",     \"question_number\": 3,     \"id\": 3}, {    \"text\": \"Walking\",     \"question_number\": 4,     \"id\": 4}, {    \"text\": \"Sitting\",     \"question_number\": 5,     \"id\": 5}]";


    try {
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(s);

        for (int i =0 ,l=array.length() ; i<l; i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
            String text = jsonObject.getString("text");
            int qNumber = jsonObject.getInt("question_number");
            int id = jsonObject.getInt("id");
           //handle here the variables ...
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: can u tel how to use url in this example

Comment: the question was about parsing JSON, you have to download the string from a url or get it from a resource or what ever